# Derive unitary matrix for Tofolli gate

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, linear-algebra

I know that for two qubits, the CNOT matrix is given by

$CNOT=P_0 \otimes I + P_1 \otimes X.$

But I cannot figure out how to get the matrix if I have two control qubits, acting on a third, like in the circuit below.
[image]

How can I derive this matrix? Thank you!

Comment: +1 Conditional-not-gate (CNOT) is explained. Clearly the step to convert into a matrix is the focus of the question. Downvoter should explain please.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I want to be able to generate the matrices on the fly, for any position of the controls and targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple formula based on the definition of tofolli gate.

Definition- If two qubits are in up states simultaneously then flip the third qubit and in other configurations do nothing.

Mathematically-

\begin{equation}|\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\uparrow_2|\otimes\sigma_x + |\uparrow_1\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\downarrow_2|\otimes I+|\downarrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle\langle\downarrow_1\uparrow_2|\otimes I+|\downarrow_1\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\downarrow_1\downarrow_2|\otimes I\end{equation}

where $\sigma_x$ is $x$-Pauli Matrix and $I$ is $2\times2$ Identity Matrix.

Up state for qubit one  $|\uparrow_1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

Down state for qubit one  $|\downarrow_1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Up state for qubit two  $|\uparrow_2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

Down state for qubit two  $|\downarrow_2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

$|\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

and $|\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\uparrow_2| = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$

Similarly you can construct other terms.

Finally,

$|\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\uparrow_2|\otimes\sigma_x + |\uparrow_1\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\uparrow_1\downarrow_2|\otimes I+|\downarrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle\langle\downarrow_1\uparrow_2|\otimes I+|\downarrow_1\downarrow_2\rangle\langle\downarrow_1\downarrow_2|\otimes I$ =

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$

Other definition "if two qubits are in down states simultaneously then flip the third qubit and do nothing in other configurations" is equally valid. You even have choice to choose $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ as down state. You can play around with these conventions and find different ways to write tofolli gate which all are equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

This gate is the so-called Toffoli gate. Its matrix representation is given by the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

. It's easy to see why, since the gate has to map $|110\rangle$ to $|111\rangle$, $|111\rangle$ to $|110\rangle$, and it has to leave the other elements of the computational basis unchanged.

I don't know whether it helps, but one can also write that matrix as

$$
M_0 \otimes I_4 + M_1 \otimes I_2 + M_2 \otimes X
$$

, where $M_0$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

, $M_1$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

, and $M_2$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} .

Comment: I know how to derive it this way, but I'm confused about the equations.

Comment: @Fernando: I can also write that matrix as a sum of three tensor products, but I have no clue whether this is the decomposition you want.

Comment: I think it's exactly that! I'm coding a simulator, that's why I need equations.

Comment: So if I have a system with n control qbits acting on a single target, I can generalize this equation (adding more terms and caring about order). Is that correct? Also, could you also elaborate a bit on M0, M1 and M2? Thank you!

Comment: @Fernando: you're right. For the present case, n=2, I found M0,M1 and M2 by "trial and error", but it's straightforward. Actually, I can write a general formula for n control qbits acting on a single target qbit (with any single qubit unitary operation, there is nothing special with X).

Comment: @Fernando: I can write a short note with the general formula and a proof and send it to you, but first I would need more information about the interest of such a formula. Could you please tell me more about the usefulness of that formula ? If more convenient for you, email me by following my webpage address in my profile.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks. My interest is to simulate some circuits, so I need to derive these matrices on the fly. I know how to do that for controlled-U gates, but not for C2-U gates.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick in Quirk (the tool you used to make your screenshot) that will show you the matrix for any operation or combination of operations. This trick is based on the [channel-state duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel-state_duality).

1. Prepare a number of EPR pairs equal to the number of qubits in your circuit. Put one half of each EPR pair in a group at the top, and the others go on the bottom in the same order. You can do this with a bunch of H+CNOT gates, or slightly more quickly with a single QFT+ADD block.
2. Apply the gates from your original circuit to the bottom half of this larger circuit.
3. Look at the output amplitude display. It's the circuit's unitary matrix! (Actually it's only proportional to the matrix, but that's just as good.)

[Here is the matrix for your circuit in Quirk, via this trick](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT3%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA3%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: circuit with matrix trick]

And the matrix for your circuit is in fact

$$\begin{bmatrix}
&&&1 \\
&&1\\
&1\\
&&&&1\\
&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

(Note: the result depends on your convention for ordering the computational basis states w.r.t. the qubits. I am assuming the top qubit is the least significant w.r.t. the ordering.)

If you play around with the circuit in Quirk while showing the matrix, it becomes very obvious very fast how to construct the matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. I posted a question about quirk in cs exchange (I'm getting a different result from another simulator).